# python cannot use exception fields in handler

Tags: python, exception

I building an assembler for a class assignment. What my program does is read files than spit out machine code, (after striping comments etc... but that all works).

What I'm tying to do is build an exception handler on top of all this so that it will catch exceptions thrown by bad code and I can handle them by printing out the line where the bad code was so it's easy to debug bad code.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to access the exception instance that was caught. Everything I find seems to give me the class object for the exception in particular.

Right now I getting errors like this:

```
AttributeError: 'UnknownCommandException' object has no attribute 'line'
```

Here is the top level program I'm handling the exceptions in now:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from assembler import readCodeFromFile
from exceptions import UndeclaredLabelException
from exceptions import UnknownCommandException
from exceptions import RegisterNotFoundException

def main():
    readFileStr = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename()
    wrtFile = readFileStr.replace(".txt","") + "ASSEMBLY.txt"
    try:
        readCodeFromFile(readFileStr, wrtFile, base="*")
    except UndeclaredLabelException as e:
        print("undeclared label '{}' near line {}".format(e.label, e.line)) 
        print(e)
    except UnknownCommandException as e:
        print("unknown command '{}' near line {}".format(e.inst, e.line))
        print(e)
    except RegisterNotFoundException as e:
        print("unknown reg '{}' near line {}".format(e.reg, e.line))
        print(e)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I also tied to use `sys.exc_info()` which did not work for me either.

The code where the exceptions are defined.

```
class RegisterNotFoundException(Exception):
    """this exception is thrown when a string does not match any of the known registers for this language."""
    def __init__ (self, reg, line):
        self.reg = reg
        self.line = line   
class UnknownCommandException(Exception):
    """this exception is thrown when a nonexistant command is used."""
    def __init__(self, inst, line):
        self.inst = inst
        self.lineNumber = line
class UndeclaredLabelException(Exception):
    """this exception is thrown when a label is used but has not been declared."""
    def __init__(self, label, line):
        self.badLabel = label
        self.lineNumber = line
    def __repr__ (self):
        return "bad label: '" + self.badLabel + "'"
```

I've found that this code handles my `RegisterNotFoundException` just fine, but not the other two, which leaves me even more confused than before.

Comment: You are catching the exceptions *just fine*. They just don't *have* the attributes you are looking for. Can you update your questions to show us how your exceptions are defined and how you are raising them?

Comment: Try just printing `e`

Comment: I've updated the code. Printing the exceptions produces what looks like a tuple to me, but will not allow indexing. e[0] causes an error.
The print result looks like "('mhvedfjkuh', 0)" with 'mhvedfjkuh' being the unrecognized assembly instruction that caused the error to be thrown, and 0 being the line it was thrown at, but I can't get at these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using inconsistent attribute names. You are handling your exceptions just fine, you simply have the names mixed up.

Two of your exceptions use `lineNumber` as the attribute:

```
class UnknownCommandException(Exception):
    """this exception is thrown when a nonexistant command is used."""
    def __init__(self, inst, line):
        self.inst = inst
        self.lineNumber = line
        #    ^^^^^^^^^^

class UndeclaredLabelException(Exception):
    """this exception is thrown when a label is used but has not been declared."""
    def __init__(self, label, line):
        self.badLabel = label
        self.lineNumber = line
        #    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

but your exception handler is trying to access the `line` attribute:

```
except UndeclaredLabelException as e:
    print("undeclared label '{}' near line {}".format(e.label, e.line)) 
    #                                                            ^^^^
    print(e)
except UnknownCommandException as e:
    print("unknown command '{}' near line {}".format(e.inst, e.line))
    #                                                          ^^^^
    print(e)
```

Also note the `UndeclaredLabelException.badLabel` vs. the `e.label` attributes.

Either rename the attributes on the class, or access the right attributes in the exception handlers.

Answer (score 0):

In the `UnknownCommandException` and `UndeclaredLableException` class initializers, the code is assigning the `line` parameter to an attribute named `lineNumber`. If you can't (or don't want to) change the exceptions, you'll need to look for that attribute in your exception handling code:

```
except UndeclaredLabelException as e:
    print("undeclared label '{}' near line {}".format(e.label, e.lineNumber)) 
    print(e)
except UnknownCommandException as e:
    print("unknown command '{}' near line {}".format(e.inst, e.lineNumber))
    print(e)
```

The `RegisterNotFoundException` does use `line` as the attribute name, so your existing code should work for those already.